# Linear programming standard form convention: RHS positive?

Tags: linear-programming

Indeed many authors have various versions of standard form LP problems, but I am wondering if the following is an essential trait:

In an LP problem we have min(f(x)) with constraint,say, $Ax\geq b$. My question is whether the RHS has to be positive when changing to standard form eg. $3x-2y\leq -5\Rightarrow -3x+2y-s= 5$?

I don't think so because the simplex method relies on comparing the pivots i.e. ratios of coeff/RHS, and so any sign difference cancels out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplex method starts with a basic feasible solution. The RHS can be negative in the standard form, but when we want to find a basic feasible solution it is much easier to have non-negative RHSs. Here are some references:

*Linear and Nonlinear Programming (David G. Luenberger, Yinyu Ye):*

[image]

*Linear Programming and Network Flows (Hanif D. Sherali, John J. Jarvis, and M. S. Bazaraa):*

> *A linear program is said to be in standard format if all restrictions are equalities and all variables are non-negative. The simplex method is designed to be applied only after the problem is put in standard form.*

[image]